# Is it possible to check what the provisioned throughput is for DynamoDB?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Is it possible for my (java) app to check DynamoDB's provisioned throughput for read/writes? For stability reasons it would be useful if I could get these numbers programmatically

I am aware that if I get a `ProvisionedThroughputExceededException` then I have exceeded my limit, but is there a way to find out what my read/write limits are *before* that happens?

I have also found some docs referring to [describing limits](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeLimits.html) but this doesn't seem to correspond to anything I can use in code

This is the first time I've used dynamodb so if this is fundamentally bad practice to do please say!

Cheers

Comment: Roughly everything you find in the generic api reference has an equivalent in the java-sdk: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/AmazonDynamoDBClient.html#describeLimits%28com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.DescribeLimitsRequest%29 (it's more or less a simple wrapper around the http api)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The aws-java-sdk allows you to do that. Similar to http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/JavaDocumentAPIWorkingWithTables.html you can do either

```
    AmazonDynamoDB dynamoClient = new AmazonDynamoDBClient();
    DescribeTableResult result = dynamoClient.describeTable("MyTable");
    Long readCapacityUnits = result.getTable()
            .getProvisionedThroughput().getReadCapacityUnits();
```

or

```
    AmazonDynamoDB dynamoClient = new AmazonDynamoDBClient();
    DynamoDB dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(dynamoClient);
    Table table = dynamoDB.getTable("MyTable");
    Long readCapacityUnits = table.describe()
            .getProvisionedThroughput().getReadCapacityUnits();
```

`DynamoDb` is a higher level wrapper, which sometimes has simpler APIs, `AmazonDynamoDBClient` is a rather straight implementation of the HTTP APIs.

For more on autoscaling dynamodb see

[How to auto scale Amazon DynamoDB throughput?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26354536/how-to-auto-scale-amazon-dynamodb-throughput)

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the [AWS SDK for Java](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/AmazonDynamoDBClient.html), like this:

```
AmazonDynamoDBClient client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient();
client.describeTable("tableName").getTable().getProvisionedThroughput();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the AWS CLI command to get the provisioned throughput for a table.

```
aws dynamodb describe-table --table-name <table name>
```