# How to configure automatically dynamodb table read and write capacity?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am facing below problem:

Consumed read capacity >= 4 for 5 minutes

I need to configure capacity dynamically not static.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to auto scale Amazon DynamoDB throughput?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26354536/how-to-auto-scale-amazon-dynamodb-throughput)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Per [DynamoDB UpdateTable Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateTable.html#API_UpdateTable_Examples)

> **UpdateTable**
>
> Modifies the provisioned throughput settings, global secondary
>   indexes, or DynamoDB Streams settings for a given table.
>
> UpdateTable is an asynchronous operation; while it is executing, the table status changes from ACTIVE to UPDATING. While it is UPDATING, you cannot issue another UpdateTable request. When the table returns to the ACTIVE state, the UpdateTable operation is complete.

You can update ReadCapacityUnits OR WriteCapacityUnits using updateTable API as below :

```
{
    "TableName": "Thread",
    "ProvisionedThroughput": {
        "ReadCapacityUnits": 10,
        "WriteCapacityUnits": 10
    }
}
```

For Example, You can Code in a Script to Increase *ReadCapacityUnits* OR *WriteCapacityUnits* **Dynamically** when ServerLoad is High & Decrease if ServerLoad is low.

Comment: @AnoopKumar did this answer help you ?